# EF Core: Multiple enum discriminators per TpH

Tags: entity-framework-core

```
               AbstractA
              /         \
       AbstractB       AbstractC
          |                  |
      ConcreteBA         ConcreteCA
```

There is an enum discriminator which defines whether it is "B" or "C" and an additional enum which describes whether its "BA" or "CA"

If enum 1 has value 1 and enum 2 has value 1 then it's "BA"

If enum 1 has value 2 and enum 2 has value 1 then it's "CA"

The Concrete classes BA and CA have class which links to a separate table

Can I create multiple discriminators to help define this for EF core?

Comment: Why do you want 2 enums? Just stick with a single one, you only need to know if it's BA or CA.

Comment: @DavidG unfortunately we are mapping to an existing data structure

Comment: @DavidG Where the old codebase used sql to linq but the new uses EF core

Comment: You can't have multiple discriminators, of that I'm pretty sure. You may be forced to use a single model for the database and project that into the relevant domain class. Always love helping out a fellow Geordie :)

Comment: If I use a single discriminator to define abstractB, the specific properties on ConcereteBA / ConcreteBB would not be pulled from the database so I don't think I would be able to manually cast to root class. Haha small world

Comment: I meant that you would not be doing TPH any more and just have a class that pulls all the columns and then you project that class to the relevant type based on some enum properties. It's really hard to suggest anything without seeing some code.

Comment: Create new computed column from existing as discriminator, thus it will not affect existing data structures.